# Pandas concatenate strings including group by column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am attempting to groupby and concatenate strings. The twist is I would like to include the groupby column in the concatenated strings.

I have already attempted the code below, and it works! But I worry I am doing this in too many steps.

```
# Create dataframe
d = {'ORDER_ID': ['order-1','order-2','order-3','order-4','order-5','order-6'], 'pillar_range': ['100','100','100','200','200','300'],'NOTES': ["wet","wet weather","flooded","fine","okay","perfect"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Create a concatinated column I want to groupby concatenate in the final step
df['concat_col'] = df['ORDER_ID']+':'+df['NOTES']
# Only select the groupby column and my newly created concatenated column
df = df[['pillar_range','concat_col']]

#  Create the final output
df = df.groupby('pillar_range').agg(lambda x: ' | '.join(set(x)))
```

Comment: Please explain `I would like to include the groupby column in the concatenated strings.` may be an example would help to make it clearer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you cut your code into one-line

```
(df['ORDER_ID']+':'+df['NOTES']).groupby(df['pillar_range']).agg(':'.join)
Out[580]: 
pillar_range
100    order-1:wet:order-2:wet weather:order-3:flooded
200                          order-4:fine:order-5:okay
300                                    order-6:perfect
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works perfectly.  I’m still getting my head around Pandas and what feels like 10 different ways to do things.